# Appcelerator - Different xml for the same controller

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

Is possible to have one `xml` for iOS and one `xml` for Android for the same controller?

For example:

I have que controller: `UIPhoto.js`

and I want to have 2 different `xml` and `tss` files: `UIPhoto-iOS.xml` and `UIPhoto-Android.xml`

and charge each when the device is iOS or Android.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible and is quite simple!
You just need to have a different folder for the specific platform you want to target.
Imagine that you have the index.xml file inside Views folder, right?
You can code your xml as you're used to and if you want a different file for Android (let's say), you just need to create a folder inside "Views" folder called Android. Check this image with a folder structure:

[image: Alloy folder structure]

Notice the Android folder in 'controllers' and the iOS in 'views' ;)

Comment: Ohhh thank you, that's what I'm looking for. I'll try it next Monday. Thank you so much. If all works okay, I'll put your answer with green tick.

Answer (score 2):

You may use platform specific folder in your views

```
controllers   
--- UIPhoto.js
views
--- android
------ UIPhoto.xml
--- iOS
------ UIPhoto.xml
```

but i recommend you to use tss rather than use 2 xml and 2 tss. 
for example in your tss:

```
"Window[platform=ios]":{
   fullscreen : true
}

"View[platform=android]" :{
   elevation : 8
}
"View[formFactor=tablet]" :{
   elevation : 8
}
"View[platform=android formFactor=handheld]" :{
   elevation : 8
}
```

and for your controller :

```
if(OS_IOS){
}
if(OS_ANDROID){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can switch xml file or tss file when device is iOS or Android.

But maybe this is helpful:

First of all you can detect OS with `Ti.Platform.osname;` in your index.js and valorize a global varibale like this `Alloy.Globals.OS`.

Now you can switch your code with a simple if statements also in js file with:

```
if(Alloy.Globals.OS == "android"){...}
```

In your tss file you can distingue platform like this:

```
"#title[platform=android]" : {
    font : { textStyle : Ti.UI.TEXT_STYLE_HEADLINE }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I know this options.I only want to know if this option that I mentioned exists.

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe you can use 'require("namefile")'. Did you try this option?